# Check if there is an post to be published in future

Tags: functions, publish

I need to check if there is an post to be published in future. I want to use WP functions, no directly access to database via mysql_query.

Has anyone some sample of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_post_status()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) within a query to get `future` posts.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'future' );
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Do stuff... -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```